# Prove that the number of divisors of a number that is a power of a natural number, is odd.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

I want to know if the number of divisors of a number is odd or even, I think that will solve me a problem.

The problem, as I see it, asks me to prove that the number of divisors for a number that is a power of a natural number - is odd.

### What I tried:

I think to prove it using induction. Not sure I'm doing it the right way.

For $n = 1:$ 1 has only one divisor – itself, and it's the power of itself so its a power of a natural number, so it holds.

For $n = n^2$, take $n^2$, it's surely a power of natural number ($n$). Aassume it holds.

Now prove for $n = (n+1)^2$ again, it's surely a power of a natural number – (n+1). Let's calculate:

$$
(n+1)^2 = n^2 + 2n + 1
$$

From the assumption we know that the number of divisors of $n^2$ is odd, from the base – the number of divisors of $1$ is odd and now we remain with $2n$... not sure what to say on him.

I would like a hint (more than a solution, as it will solve me homework)

Maybe something with prime factorization? But my proof should be general and not for a particular number.

Thank for any help.

Comment: How many divisors does $8$ have?

Comment: I think you mean an $\textbf{even}$ power.

Comment: i meant square...

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to prove it, since it is not true: $8=2^3$ and it has $4$ divisors.

What is true is that [a natural number $n$ has an odd number of divisors if and only if it is a perfect square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906159/a-number-is-a-perfect-square-if-and-only-if-it-has-odd-number-of-positive-diviso).

Answer (score 0):

A square ($n^2$) has an odd number of factors (including $1$ as a factor), and every other natural number has an even number of factors.

Think about an example:  $12$.  Its factors are $1,2,3,4,6,12$.  They are paired:  $(1,12)$, $(2,6)$, $(3,4)$... and hence an even number of them.  This holds for every non-square number (even primes).

For a square this is *not* the case:  Example $36$.  Its (paired) factors are $(1,36)$, $(2,18)$, $(3,12)$, $(4,9)$, and [drum roll please...], $(6,?)$.  Because $36$ is a square, its square root factor has *ITSELF* as the paired factor.

Hence perfect squares have an *odd* number of factors.

Answer (score 0):

For every divisor $d$ of $n$ we have $\frac nd$ is also a divisor of $n$.

So so the divisors of $n$ come in pairs,  $(d_i, \frac {n}{d_i})$.

The only divisors that are *not* in distinct pairs will occur when you have a divisor $d$ and $\frac nd = d$.  But that will occur if and only if $n = d^2$.

So.... If $n$ is a perfect square, or in other words, an ***even*** power of a natural number you will  have *one* singleton odd divisor $d = \sqrt n$. And a set of distinct pairs of divisors $(d_i, \frac n{d_i})$.  And so if $n$ is a perfect square it will have an odd number of divisors

If $n$ is not a perfect square, then all the divisors will be in pairs and $\sqrt n$ will not be an integer divisor.  So if $n$ is not a perfect square it will have an even number of divisors.

(Note:  All numbers are powers, but maybe only to the power of $1$ and not necessarily a power of a *prime*. If it's to an odd power then it has an even number of divisors.  If its an even power then it has an odd number of divisors.  But unless it is a power of *one prime* number, the powers will not tell you how many divisors, so there is little to be gained by asking the question in terms whether a number is a power or not.  It's *much* more relevant to ask whether it is a perfect square or not.)