# Generate number with odd number of divisors

Tags: combinatorics, prime-numbers

I need to find the number of numbers from 1 to n that will have an odd number of divisors. For example, 4 has 3 divisors - 1,2,4. Knowing that such numbers are formed by raising prime numbers to an even power in their product (2^2 = 4, 3^2 = 9, 2^2 * 3^2 = 36, etc.), I I want to generate these numbers until I reach n and then I can count how many there were, but I don’t understand which square of the prime number to add at each step to go in ascending order. For example, to get the first number with an odd number of divisors we raise the prime number 2 to the 2nd power = 4, the next in ascending order will be 3 to the 2nd power = 9, but the next in ascending order will NOT be 5 to the 2nd power = 25, but 2 to the 4th power = 16 and only then comes 5 to the 2nd power. Is there an algorithm to iterate in ascending order over all numbers with an odd number of divisors using the product of prime numbers to even powers?

Comment: But who cares about the factorization? Can't you just count the perfect squares in $\{1,\cdots,n\}$ ?

Comment: $$2^4=4^2$$ might enlighten you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the divisors of a natural number $n$ are split into pairs in the following way: $a$ and $b$ go in pair if $ab=n$. Since all the divisors are in pairs, there is an even number of them.

When would this reasoning not work? When $a$ and $b$ are the same number. So $n=a^2$. Hence squares have always odd number of divisors.

Example: consider $12$. Its divisors are: $1-12$, $2-6$, $3-4$, they go in pairs. Now consider $16$. Divisors: $1-16$, $2-8$, $4$. The number $4$ here is the “pair to itself”, since $16=4^2$.

Knowing this, there are $\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor$ numbers which have odd number of divisors in $\{1,2,…,n\}$.

Comment: +1: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906159/a-number-is-a-perfect-square-if-and-only-if-it-has-odd-number-of-positive-diviso

Comment: thank you, it works faster than my method

Comment: @Aig one more question - how to get number of ways to get this number with odd divisors?For example, for 4 there are 4 ways to get it for 2 multiplier : 4*1, 1*4, 2*2, 2*2 (order matters)

Comment: @Ivan It doesn’t make sense to use $1$ when generating numbers in such way. Otherwise, you could say that $1\times1\times4$ is yet another way. Also, I don’t quite understand why and how you distinguish $2\times2$ and $2\times2$.

Comment: @Ivan Maybe the answer to this question is the number of divisors of generated number minus $1$. If $n=p_1^{a_1}…p_k^{a_k}$ is the prime factorization, then there is $(a_1+1)…(a_k+1)$ divisors of $n$. So for example, for $12$ we have $2\times6= 3\times4=4\times3=6\times2=12$.